# Using hive commands in shell script

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

I have a problem where I need to pass columns to a shell script that will be utilized inside another shell script. Then I need to iterate over the columns and do some processing; I want to store the output in a Hive table.

But I don't understand how should I store the output of each iteration in the same Hive table.
Can anyone suggest me how it can be done?

`#!/bin/bash
./hive -S -e "use telecom;select case when $1/2>avg($1) over (partition by 1) then $1 end from telecom_tr1;"`

I am passing here only one column name but, is it possible to pass multiple column names and save the output in a single Hive table?

***Edits:***

Example output my hive output table should look like this if i give three columns as input to my shell script.Script will iterate over parameters passed Query will do some processing for each iteration and should store result in one hive table only for each iteration(column)

```
scrip input: sh test.sh col1 col2 col3

expected output: iteration one | iteration two | iteration three
```

Comment: Have you though about creating a partitioned table?

Comment: No i did not how will partition solve my problem?

Comment: could you provide more info regarding what u are trying to achieve here. may be an example output .. irrespective of its working or not ?

Comment: i edited my question to add more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create partitioned tables in Hive which will easily solve this problem.  The basic format would look something like this:

```
create table my_table (field string) partitioned by (iter int);

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table partition (iter=${iter})
select case when $1/2>avg($1) over (partition by 1) then $1 end from telecom_tr1;
```

This will return the results from each run of the query appended to each other with a column called iter specifying which iteration the result comes from.

Comment: hi
thanks for the solution it worked is it possible to show Column name in the partition? instead of number?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean - but you can set ${iter} to be anything you want it to be...

Answer (score 0):

following is a crude way of doing it

--myQuery.hql

```
  use telecom;

  Create table my_temp_table_${iterationNo} as
  select my_temp_table_${old_iterationNo}.* ,(select case when $iterationNo/2>avg($iterationNo) over (partition by 1) then $1 end from telecom_tr1;) as Iteration_2 
  from my_temp_table_${old_iterationNo};

  drop table my_temp_table_${old_iterationNo};
```

in Bash just iterate over the the params which you got call the HQL as

```
  hive -d iterationNo = $current -d old_iterationNo=$prev -f myQuery.hql
```

Comment: i tried something similar  in shell script inside for loop in each iteration it will create a table and overwrite previous iterations results that was the problem i was facing..

Comment: and i need to pass column name as input to shell script. i ddnt understand iterationNo = $current -d old_iterationNo=$prev 
and i should be able to pass multiple column names as a parameter t oshell script